# Device onboarding in IBM Bluemix platform

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, watson-iot, device-management

I have a few questions regarding onboarding a thing in IBM Bluemix IOT. My questions are as follows:

1. In scenario 1: Let's say I need to connect only one thing to the Bluemix platform, so I configure the device type, device, authentication token, etc., to connect the device to the platform. This is possible in the current situation.
2. In scenario 2: If I need to connect 50 things to my platform, will I be configuring each and every device to get the device ID, token, etc.?

Does Bluemix provide any discovery mechanism or other ways to configure things automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically register devices using bulk/devices operations. https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/swagger/v0002.html#!/Bulk_Operations/post_bulk_devices_add

Also, this [recipe](https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/multiple-iot-device-simulation-using-java-client-library/) describes how to register multiple IoT devices.

If you are using a gateway, devices can be [auto registered:](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/gateways/mqtt.html)
look for "Gateway auto-registration"

Here are some other links that may be helpful.
This recipe talks in detail about how to register a device in Watson IoT Platform - https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/how-to-register-devices-in-ibm-iot-foundation/

This Java sample shows how one can do bulk addition/deletion - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/iot-platform-apiv2-samples/blob/master/java/api-samples-v2/README.md

Comment: Thanks for the inputs ValerieLampkin. Appreciate your help !

Comment: Hi Valerie ,  I have a question knocking in my mind. I wish to discover my things in a network through network protocols such as (CoAP) rather than API's . Does bluemix provide this support ?

Comment: At this point, the Watson IoT platform service in Bluemix uses MQTT protocol and not CoAP.  You may be able to create a "gateway" that uses CoAP to gather the info from other devices but only the gateway using MQTT would be able to communicate directly to the Watson IoT Platform.